# My Content Provider to Rest with Broadcast is having Infinite loop

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, intentservice, android-contentresolver, android-broadcast

I watched the virgil's android rest google io video and trying to implement it.

In short this is the problem but please read on for details.

ContentResolver query -> Content Provider Query -> Start Database update Service, make query, return cursor

The service -> update database ->Broadcast database update

Activity -> register broadcast -> on receive Contentresolver query. (we are back in the beginning)

This became an infinite loop.

In my content provider, for query method. I start Intent service which uses the rest service. Then the query method queries the local database and returns the cursor. In the onhandle() method of the intent service,  I retrieve new content from web service and writes to the database. Then I send a local broadcast with an action.

In my activity I register the broadcast and onreceive(). I call the contentresolver.query to get new content from the database. This apparently is creating a circular problem. I am back in content provider query..service..broadcast.

I want to be able to stop the broadcast after its received.

How can I solve this. Should I use SQLitedatabase query rather than content resolver? or should I send the broadcast differently. can I send another parameter with content resolver query like broadcastAfterUpdateOn and Off? Should I derive content resolver and create a custom query method?

Comment: One thing I could do is to broadcast with the new content. So in onreceive method, I query the intent for the new content. I don't have to call the content resolver query again. that would break the loop, but is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Don't send notification if there is no new item in the REST result.

```
long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(getTableName(), null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
if (id < 0) {
  return null;
}
Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(getContentURI(), values.getAsInteger(getIdFieldName()));
Log.d(TAG, "New profile URI: " + newUri.toString());
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
```